# Problems with running an ipynb file

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

Hello I hope you are well. The problem I have is that a box in the program does not run, in this screenshot I show you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJewi.png)

When running the cell the program does not work and this appears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qepGp.png)

Please if you can help me, I have reviewed several tutorials and this is how it is done, but it doesn't work for me. I know it's something basic, that's why it frustrates me that I can't solve it.

Thanks for your time

What I hope to understand is why it doesn't work if I have done everything that was requested and be able to run the program.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)